# Can I stop/cancel an already running Asynchronous NSMutableURLRequest by setting it to nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest

As the question says, will the following help? I have not set any delegate to the request. Am I better off setting delegates?

```
request = nil;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. NSMutableURLRequest can not 'run'. NSMutableURLRequest is just an object that stores url, body and some other options. To run it you should use NSURLConnection, example:

```
NSURLConnection* your_connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:your_request delegate:delegate];
```

or NSURLSession which returns NSURLSessionTask, example:

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *sessionTask = [NSURLSession downloadTaskWithRequest:your_request];
```

To cancel connection/task you should call

```
[your_connection cancel];
```

or

```
[sessionTask cancel];
```

depending on what do you use.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot find "cancel" for NSMutableURLRequest.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Of course not. An NSURLRequest is just a data structure _describing_ a request. It's not something you could cancel. You start an NSURLConnection for a request, and then you can cancel the NSURLConnection. Cancelling the NSURLRequest, if there was a method for it, couldn't possibly work because starting the NSURLConnection _copies_ the request.

Comment: @user2573339 I have updated the answer to make it more clear. Please check.

Comment: @gnasher729 and Avt, thank you for making it clear. I'm currently using the block.
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
    { //call another method}

I have the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate set to the class where I am initiating connections from. I looked at [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
 but could not find a cancel delegate.

Comment: @user2573339 is it possible for you to switch to another NSURLConnection method?

Comment: @Avt. I'm afraid not. If it cannot be done this way. I think I'm out of options. Thanks for the insights anyways. I'll stop doing further requests till I get responses from other requests for now.

Comment: You'll need to call something like the connectionWithRequest:delegate: method and keep track of the NSURLConnection that it returns. Then you can call "cancel" on the NSURLConnection.